# Are apps published through Adobe Flash's "IPhone OS" packager be approved on the Apple store?

Tags: iphone, flash, appstore-approval, packager-for-iphone

I this that this question is well described on the title: Are apps published through Adobe Flash's "IPhone OS" packager be approved on the Apple store?

Comment: That's a question for Apple. It's not a programming question. App submission questions should go to Apple directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes see http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/adobe-resurrects-flash-tool-after-apple-about-face/ and http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/app_store_guide.html